# Prevent my Fixed Footer from overlapping content

Tags: html, css, position, overlap

I have the following code to create my fixed footer: (Similar to https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_fixed_footer)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.footer {
   position: fixed;
   left: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   width: 100%;
   background-color: red;
   color: white;
   text-align: center;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Fixed/Sticky Footer Example</h2>
<p>The footer is placed at the bottom of the page.</p>
<p>The footer is placed at the bottom of the page.</p>
.....
<p>The footer is placed at the bottom of the page.</p>
<p>The footer is placed at the bottom of the page.</p>
<p>The footer is placed at the bottom of the page.</p>
<p>The footer is placed at the bottom of the page.</p>
<p>The footer is placed at the bottom of the page.</p>
<p>N-2 element</p>
<p>N-1 element</p>
<p>N element</p>

<div class="footer">
  <p>Footer</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

The fixed property is working great but I am not seeing the last line of my contet. The footer is overlapping it:

[image]

How can I avoid it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need to add height to your footer and then to add padding-bottom: footerHeightpx; to the body element

```
body {
  padding-bottom: footerHeightHere
}
```

Comment: Your solution + background-color property did the job